# University exercise, i'm trying to understand what this means

Tags: c++

```
const int N = 5;

struct array_str {
    int array[N];
    unsigned int size;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}

void readArray(array_str& v){
    
    for (<#initialization#>; <#condition#>; <#increment#>) {
        <#statements#>
    }
    
}
```

What does "array_str& v" means in the parenthesis? I'm not passing the struct bcs I would do that in this way "struct array_str *name*", *v* is a variable but why would you write it like that?

Comment: This is not the right platform to ask questions about basic language syntax. It's a reference.

Comment: [Looks like you should get a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: And by "it's a reference" we mean to say `array_str& v` means that `v` is a reference to struct `array_str`. It is not needed to specify struct there.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the parameter of the type `array_str`  passed as `reference` under the name *v* when you call the function `readArray`